# How to stub a dependency in express middleware (express-validator/mocha/chai/sinon/proxyquire)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mocha.js

****Edit:** Re-written with a simple example that works first:

So I've got a test file and 2 modules.

`moduleA` has a dependency, `moduleB`

```
// moduleA.js
const ModuleB = require('./moduleB');

function functionA() {
  return 20 + ModuleB.functionB();
};

module.exports = { functionA };


// moduleB.js
const functionB = () => {
  return 10;
}

module.exports = { functionB }
```

My test file stubs out `functionB` (returned from `moduleB`) using proxyquire:

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');

describe('Unit Tests', function() {
  it('should work', () => {
    const mockedFn = sinon.stub();
    mockedFn.returns(30);

    const copyModuleA = proxyquire('./moduleA', {
      './moduleB': {
        functionB: mockedFn
      }
    });

    console.log(copyModuleA.functionA());
  })
});
```

So it outputs `50` (stubbed functionB `30` + functionA `20`)

---

Now I'm trying to take this example into my code:

moduleA in this case is a file called `validation.js`. It is dependent on moduleB, in this case a sequelize model, `Person`, with the function I want to mock: `findOne`

`validation.js` exports `module.exports = { validateLogin };`, a function that calls `validate`, which returns a function that uses `Person.findOne()`

So in my mind, as with the simple example, I need to create a stub, point to the validation module in `proxyquire`, and reference the dependency and its `findOne` function. Like this:

```
const stubbedFindOne = sinon.stub();
stubbedFindOne.resolves();
validationModule = proxyquire('../../utils/validation', {
  '../models/Person': {
    findOne: stubbedFindOne
  }
});
```

This *should* stub `Person.findOne` in `validation.js`. But it doesn't seem to. And I have no idea why.

```
let validationModule;

describe('Unit Tests', () => {
  before(() => {
    const stubbedFindOne = sinon.stub();
    stubbedFindOne.resolves();
    validationModule = proxyquire('../../utils/validation', {
      '../models/Person': {
        findOne: stubbedFindOne
      }
    });

  }) 
  it.only('should return 422 if custom email validation fails', async() => {

    const wrongEmailReq = { body: {email: 'nik@hotmail.com'} };

    const res = {
      statusCode: 500,
      status: (code) => {this.statusCode = code; return this},
    };
  
    const validationFn = validationModule.validateLogin();
    const wrongEmail = await validationFn(wrongEmailReq, res, ()=>{});

    expect(wrongEmail.errors[0].msg).to.be.equal('Custom Authorisation Error');

    return;
  })
```

And this is my `validation.js` file:

```
const Person = require('../models/Person');

// parallel processing
const validate = validations => {
  return async (req, res, next) => {
    await Promise.all(validations.map(validation => validation.run(req)));

    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (errors.isEmpty()) {
      return next();
    }

    const error = new Error();
    error.message = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'? 'Validation Failed':'Error';

    error.statusCode = !errors.isEmpty()? 422:500;
    error.errors = errors.array({onlyFirstError: true});
    next(error);
    return error;
  };
};

const validateLogin = () => {
  const validations = [
    body('email')
    .isString()
    // snip
    .custom(async (value, {req}) => {
        try{
            const person = await Person.findOne({ where: { email: value } });
            
            if(!person) return Promise.reject('Custom Authorisation Error'); 

        } catch(err) {
          throw err;
        }
    })
    .trim(),
  ];

  return validate(validations);
}

module.exports = {
  validateLogin
};
```

Answer (score 0):

So the code in both the small sample and my app *is* correct, apart from how I stub the function. It shouldn't `resolve` or `reject` anything (I tried both out of desperation). It should return `null` in order to satisfy the conditional rather than jump to the catch block:

```
    try{
        const person = await Person.findOne({ where: { email: value } });
        
        if(!person) return Promise.reject('Custom Authorisation Error'); 

    } catch(err) {
      throw err;
    }
```

Hope the simple example helps someone else with proxyquire though